# how do i skip empty values supplied to %s in python flask mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-connector-python

For example im doing a query to my database

```
try:
            dbConn = DatabasePool.getConnection()
            cursor = dbConn.cursor(dictionary=True)
            sqlquery = f"update table set name=%s if(name=%s is not null),description=%s if(description=%s is not null) where jsonid=%s"
            cursor.execute(
                sqlquery, (JSON['name'], JSON['description'], jsonid))

            dbConn.commit()
            rows = cursor.rowcount
            return rows

        finally:
            dbConn.close()
```

if i leave the name field blank. i will still be able to update my description likewise for my name.

how do i go about it doing it with the %s

i have also tried another way

```
sql = f"update table set name=if(name is null, name, %s), description = if(description is null, description, %s) where jsonID=%s"
            cursor.execute(
                sql, (JSON['name'], JSON['description'], jsonid))
```

i have to provide the 2 fields, if not it will throw me an 500 internal server error if one of the field is less.

Comment: `if(name=%s is not null)` is not valid SQL, in several ways.  There is no IF clause in the UPDATE statement, and `IS NOT NULL` applies to columns, not to expressions.  What are you trying to do here?  If you're trying to check whether `JSON['name']` is empty, you do that in the Python code, NOT in the SQL code.

Comment: i wish to update several columns when the admin fill up the fields. for example he fills up the description but leaves the name field blank and submit.

i have tried sqlquery = (sql = "update movie set name=%s,description=%s, where movieID=%s" 

but if i leave the name empty. I will hit an error of internal server error. I have to supply both fields. 

So you meant that i need to do a if else statement in the python code first before querying to the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the set of fields you're updating is variable, then you need to build your query dynamically.  Note here that I add additional "SET" clauses based on which fields are present.

```
        clauses = []
        values = []
        if JSON['name']:
            clauses.append( 'name=%s' )
            values.append( JSON['name'] )
        if JSON['description']:
            clauses.append( 'description=%s' )
            values.append( JSON['description'] )
        if values:
            values.append( jsonid )
            cursor = dbConn.cursor(dictionary=True)
            sqlquery = "UPDATE table SET " + (','.join(clauses)) + " WHERE jsonid=%s;"
            cursor.execute( sqlquery, values )
            rows = cursor.rowcount
            dbConn.commit()
            return rows
```

If you have more than just these two fields, you can make it even more automated:

```
        for column in ('name','description'):
            if JSON[column]:
                clauses.append( column + '=%s' )
                values.append( JSON[column] )
```

Comment: thanks for your assistance tim, however i'm not sure why it still require me to enter both field, even when i set dynamically for the query and value. i added the print to console portion. yo ucould see if both fields are entered. it will allow me to update in my put route. however when i leave blank. it will err 500.

Comment: hey tim, i got it to work. as my request.json comes in dictionary. using a if 'key' in dic: statement helps thanks